# Sympy inversion of exponents

Tags: python, sympy

I am having issues with how Sympy simplifies and deals with exponents. For example, consider the equation

```
a^x - b^x = 0
```

with all variables positive and real. I would expect `solve` to return `a=b`, but instead I get `a = b^{x/x}`.

Below is the MWE:

```
from sympy import *
aa, bb, xx = symbols('a, b, x', Positive = True, real = True)
solve(aa**xx - bb**xx, aa)
```

which returns

```
[(b**x)**(1/x)]
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to write `positive` in lowercase?

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`a=b^{x/x}` is the same like `a=b` or not?

**Edit:**

I have tried it with

```
solve((aa - bb) ** xx, aa)
```

In this case the return is `[0**(1/x) + b]`. If I try it to simplify with the simplify function of sympy, nothing is happening.

Maybe you should try it with:

```
solve((aa - bb) ** xx, aa)[0].subs({xx:1})
```

Then my return is `b`

Comment: I would like sympy to cancel out x. In a more complicated equation with exponent, I would like sympy to these simplifications for me.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.